# Task manager shows RAM is full but with what? Numbers don't add up

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, memory, task-manager

There's 16 GB RAM and Task Manager shows it as full. The other tab where I can see the breakdown of what's taking the space doesn't show it. What is taking all this space and how can I actually see it?

This is the host PC and I'm running virtualbox on it with Ubuntu guests. I suspect this is taking the space but I don't understand why can't I see it in the Task manager of the host. It only shows usage of few MBs of RAM for each guest.

[image: -]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't expect the VirtualBox process itself to require much memory or CPU usage.  In any event, the reason it does not make sense, is because you are looking at the wrong process.  Please [edit] your question and provide another screenshot of the services running on your machine

Comment: Note how you already have 28 GiB of commit charge. // The "Processes" tab is mostly useless. The "Details" tab and its many selectable columns offer more insight.

Comment: @DanielB - It would actually be the "Services" tab that would be more helpful since we are talking about a VirtualBox VM managed by a headless VirtualBox service.

Comment: Its likely system caching that uses otherwise unused memory to try speed up reads.  It can be released by the OS when needed by an application.

Comment: No caching going on here (well, 317 MiB). This is clear from the “Performance” tab screenshot. // The “Services” tab gives no RAM information and is if no help whatsoever here.

Comment: I would always suggest to screenshot RAMMap and provide that.